# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scandir'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scandir, python-os

I have no idea why this is happening. Here's the function:

```
def scanWallDir(basedir, scansubdirs=True):
    wallsOut = []
    for entry in os.scandir(basedir):
        if entry.is_file():
            print(("file " + entry.name))
        elif entry.is_dir():
            print(("dir  " + entry.name))
```

And the error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/aidan/Code/ulwscs/ulwscs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aidan/Code/ulwscs/ulwscs.py", line 38, in <module>
    scanWallDir("/media/Crossover/Wallpapers")
  File "/home/aidan/Code/ulwscs/ulwscs.py", line 11, in scanWallDir
    for entry in os.scandir(basedir):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scandir'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what could be heppening?

Comment: It was added in 3.5. And you don't actually use Python 3.

Comment: @vaultah Oh, Pycharm reset the interpreter. Missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pycharm reset which version of Python I was using. I'm an idiot.